# Get result from linked celery task

Tags: python, celery

Let's say I have two tasks:  `add` and `subtract`.

Now let's say I call these as follows:

```
add.apply_async((1337, 1337), link=subtract.s(40))
```

Is there a way to get the result of the subtract task?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get result of `linked` tasks from the parent task.

Lets add 10, 20 using `add` and then substract 5 from the result using linked `sub` task.

```
In [20]: r = add.apply_async([10, 20], link=sub.s(5))

In [21]: r.state
Out[21]: 'SUCCESS'

In [22]: r.result
Out[22]: 30

In [23]: r.children[0].state
Out[23]: 'SUCCESS'

In [24]: r.children[0].result
Out[24]: 25
```